# Carregar informações _Layout.cshtml vindas de banco de dados

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor, entity-framework-6

Quero carregar as informações no `_Layout.cshtml` conforme cadastradas no banco de dados, por exemplo, `@ViewBag.MetaDescription`, `@ViewBag.MetaKeywords`, `@ViewBag.Title` e outras informações também vindas do banco.

Qual a melhor maneira pra fazer isso?

Quero carregar isso apenas uma vez, pensei em até usar e armazenar isso tudo em `Session`.

Comment: Não seria melhor disponibilizar esses dados em um resource na aplicação?
Entendo que esses dados geralmente não são alterados com frequência e são apenas parâmetros do sistema.

Answer (score -1):

> Qual a melhor maneira pra fazer isso?

Não fazendo nada. O ASP.NET MVC tem uma propriedade [`HttpContext.Cache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache(v=vs.110).aspx) que faz a cache automática para você. Você só precisa definir o seguinte no seu *Controller* comum:

```
public class Controller : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
    protected readonly SeuProjetoContext context = new SeuProjetoContext();

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        var configuracao = context.Configuracoes.FirstOrDefault();
        ViewBag.MetaDescription = configuracao.MetaDescription;
        ViewBag.MetaKeywords = configuracao.MetaDescription;
        ViewBag.Title = // defina Title aqui
    }
}
```

Como a carga dessa tabela de configurações é frequente, o *cache* é automático.

Ainda assim, você pode definir o *cache* manualmente:

```
HttpContext.Cache["MetaDescription"] = "Alguma descrição";
```